# How does Thread.currentThread() work when there are multiple processors?

Tags: java, multithreading, multicore

`Thread.currentThread()` can use to get the currently executing thread. And as I think both of the sleep and yield methods are static because they can't execute sleep or yield on other threads. So by making them static it will sleep or yield only the currently executing thread.

This seems to be working in single processor system, if I call`Thread.currentThread()` or sleep then there's only the currently running thread, it will return or it will sleep. But in a multicore system, multiple threads can run at once,

So how `Thread.currentThread()` or `Thread.sleep()` works...?

Comment: This is totally OS specific; it's the role of the JVM here to make those work accurately.

Comment: Just to clarify the answers already given: _current_ doesn't mean _currently executing_. It means the thread you are calling the static method from.

Comment: The name is a relic of ancient days when there really was only one CPU.  Back then, the thread that called the method really was _the_ current thread.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The method `Thread.currentThread()` returns the thread which we are currently running inside. It is simply a way of saying: "Hey give me a reference of the thread that is running me"

Suppose we have four cores and four threads A,B,C and D are running absolutely concurrently, calling this method at the same time, it will return A, B, C and D appropriately based upon the thread we are currently in.

And methods `Thread.currentThread().sleep()` or `Thread.sleep()` are doing essentially the same job. As per the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#currentThread()) for currentThread():

> public static Thread currentThread()
>
> Returns a reference to the currently executing thread object.

and

> public static void sleep(long millis)throws InterruptedException
>
> Causes the currently executing thread to sleep (temporarily cease execution) for the specified number of milliseconds, subject to the precision and accuracy of system timers and schedulers. The thread does not lose ownership of any monitors.

Comment: What is difference between currentThread.sleep and Thread.sleep?

Answer (score 4):

The documentation is very poor in this case. What `Thread.currentThread()` returns is actually the thread where you execute that line of code in. So whether you are in a multi-processor environment or not doesn't matter in this case.

When you have two threads `ThreadA` and `ThreadB` running completely in parallel and you ask for `Thread.currentThread()` in parallel at the same time you will get the corresponding thread where this is executed.

Answer (score 3):

These methods are static because you can access to the current  **execution thread** of your core/CPU that is executing that code.

If there is more than one core or CPU processors, each core that passes through this code will return to you its own thread.

So you don't need to care about how many cores/CPUs are in the system, these methods will work in both scenarios a single core and multicore systems.

Remember that Java `Thread` is an abstraction of the OS real Thread (posix, windows...) so you can code your program without caring about OS architectures.

Answer (score 1):

it works only for the "current" thread. In a multicore system if your code is single threaded only one thread is running and this is the current one so this code will work on that one. If you have multithreading program this code will work in the thread it is called. The number of cores doesn't really matter. Java distributes the threads and the load to the different cores but from code's point of view number of processors doesn't matter.